# Basic array slice situation

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains pagenames, I want to list that names with `php echo`, but not all of them. I want second and third only, after first and fourth ... etc.

Here is my code:

```
$pagename = [
    1 => 'Homepage', 
    2 => 'Categories', 
    3 => 'Textures',
    4 => 'Tutorials',
    5 => 'Login',
    6 => 'Join'
];

foreach($pagename as $list) {
    array_slice($list, 1,-1);

    echo "<h1>{$list}</h1>";
}
```

This giving me an error:

> array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in..

I want to `echo` 'Categories', 'Textures', 'Tutorials', 'Login', 'Join'

Can you help me please?

Comment: You need to be more clear in what you have and what you want.

Comment: I want to echo second, third and fourth variables in that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line `array_slice($list, 1,-1);` and it will work

If you need to remove any element, or choose specific indexes, you need to manipulate the array.

```
$startIndex = 2;
$endIndex = 5;
for($i = $startIndex; $i <= $endIndex; $i++) {
    echo '<h1>';
    echo $pagename[$i];
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `array_slice` like your original idea

```
foreach(array_slice($pagename, 1) as $list){
    echo '<h1>';
    echo $list;
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

Comment: Nope, if i remove this line, listing all variables in that array. I'm asking spesific ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array of the keys you want and then loop that:

```
foreach(array(2, 3, 4) as $key){
    echo '<h1>';
    echo $pagename[$key];
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

Alternately check the key:

```
foreach($pagename as $key => $list){
    if(in_array($key, array(2, 3, 4)) {
        echo '<h1>';
        echo $list;
        echo '</h1>';
    }
}
```

Or you would need to loop the sliced array:

```
foreach(array_slice($pagename, 1, -1) as $list){
    echo '<h1>';
    echo $list;
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

The first two examples allow you to skip items and do things like `1, 3, 5` etc...